# Adding delimiter every n places in every line

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-2.0

How can I extend this script to add delimiters in every line.

```
apple123456NewYorkCity
nissan98766BostonMA
...
...

$x = somefile.txt
$y = @( ($x[0..4] -join ''), ($x[5..10] -join ''), 
($x[11..17] -join ''),
($x[18..21] -join ''))

$z = $y -join '|' 
$z > somenewfile.txt
```

Is the foreach code like this?

```
$x| %{@( ($_[0..4] -join ''), ($_[5..10] -join ''), 
($_[11..17] -join ''),
($_[18..21] -join ''))}??
```

Comment: I don't think it's clear what you want. 'apple' is 5 characters, 'nissan' is 6, if you add the delimiter in a fixed position it will be wrong for one or other of your two examples. Also you appear to have posted some code that doesn't do anything because you're not reading the file, but as far as it might work, it does exactly what you want - $z is fixed size parts joined with a delimiter. That's what you are asking for, you already have it. What's the foreach supposed to add?

Comment: I can easily see nissan will be nissa|n and I'll try to remove it or move the line to a new file.    apple123456NewYorkCityapples123456NewYorkCity|||  - got this as a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'ld use REGEX for this kind of job, to avoid problems with different parts lenghts:

```
Get-Content .\somefile.txt | % { $_ -replace '(\D*[^\d]*)(\d*[^\D]*)(.+)','$1 $2 $3' }
```

Comment: Oh, better idea. You put ) at the end instead of } which might be a typo. If I change your replacement to `'$1|$2|$3'` then a sample output is `apple|123456|NewYorkCity||` - where is the extra pipe at the end coming from?

Answer (score 0):

And suddenly it is clear what you want.

Long form:

```
$lines = Get-Content "somefile.txt"
ForEach ($x in $lines) {
    $y = "$($x[0..4] -join '')|$($x[5..10] -join '')|$($x[11..17] -join '')|$($x[18..21] -join '')"
    $z = $y -join '|'
    Write-Output $z | Out-File -FilePath "somenewfile.txt" -Append
}
```

Short form:

```
gc somefile.txt | % { "$($_[0..4] -join '')|$($_[5..10] -join '')|$($_[11..17] -join '')|$($_[18..21] -join '')" } >> somenewfile.txt
```

I got rid of the building an array and joining it, and replaced it with string expansion where the string has the delimiters in it; for viewers, the pattern is:

```
"$()|$()|$()"  #expressions in a string, separated by bars

"$($_[0..4] -join '')|.."  #each expression is taking characters 
                           #and joining the resulting array into a string
                           #$_.SubString(n,m) would return a string directly
                           #but it complains if you go past the end of the
                           #string, whereas $_[n..m] does not
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution with regex:

```
(cat file) -replace '\d+|\D+','$0 '

apple 123456 NewYorkCity
nissan 98766 BostonMA
```